# R - Loading External Indicators into Quantstrat

Tags: r, csv, quantmod, quantstrat

I noticed that Quantstrat typically takes indicators that are based on price. However, I would like to load several indicators that have been externally calculated along with the price data. For instance, I have 2 extra columns in a csv file that contain my indicators (numbered 1-9). I want to generate a signal based on the numbers in these columns.

Thus far, I have been unable to get Quantstrat to read the columns in the csv file. I've attached my code below:

```
 library(quantmod)
 library(quantstrat)
 library(PerformanceAnalytics)
 library(foreach)
 library(FinancialInstrument)

 getSymbols("SPY", from = "2015-12-21", to = "2016-12-20", src = "yahoo", adjust =TRUE)

    read.csv("/Users/tylerdrust/Downloads/2016 Demark Indicators.csv", 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

             Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume Adj.Close TD.Sell.Count TD.Buy.Count
1   12/21/15 201.41 201.88 200.09 201.67  99094300    197.43             0            0
2   12/22/15 202.72 203.85 201.55 203.50 111026200    199.22             0            0
3   12/23/15 204.69 206.07 204.58 206.02 110987200    201.69             0            0
4   12/24/15 205.72 206.33 205.42 205.68  48539600    201.36             0            0
5   12/28/15 204.86 205.26 203.94 205.21  65899900    200.90             1            0
6   12/29/15 206.51 207.79 206.47 207.40  92640700    203.04             2            0
7   12/30/15 207.11 207.21 205.76 205.93  63317700    201.60             0            1
8   12/31/15 205.13 205.89 203.87 203.87 102929500    199.58             0            2
9     1/4/16 200.49 201.03 198.59 201.02 222353500    196.79             0            3
10    1/5/16 201.40 201.90 200.05 201.36 110845800    197.13             0            4
11    1/6/16 198.34 200.06 197.60 198.82 152112600    194.64             0            5
12    1/7/16 195.33 197.44 193.59 194.05 213436100    189.97             0            6
13    1/8/16 195.19 195.85 191.58 191.92 209817200    187.89             0            7
14   1/11/16 193.01 193.41 189.82 192.11 187941300    188.07             0            8
15   1/12/16 193.82 194.55 191.14 193.66 172330500    189.59             0            9
16   1/13/16 194.45 194.86 188.38 188.83 221168900    184.86             0           10
17   1/14/16 189.55 193.26 187.66 191.93 240795600    187.90             1            0
18   1/15/16 186.77 188.76 185.52 187.81 314240200    183.86             0            1
19   1/19/16 189.96 190.11 186.20 188.06 195244400    184.11             0            2
20   1/20/16 185.03 187.50 181.02 185.65 286547800    181.75             0            3
21   1/21/16 186.21 188.87 184.64 186.69 195772900    182.77             0            4
22   1/22/16 189.78 190.76 188.88 190.52 168319600    186.51             1            0
23   1/25/16 189.92 190.15 187.41 187.64 130371700    183.70             0            1
24   1/26/16 188.42 190.53 188.02 190.20 141036800    186.20             1            0
25   1/27/16 189.58 191.56 187.06 188.13 185681700    184.18             2            0
26   1/28/16 189.96 190.20 187.16 189.11 143798800    185.13             0            1
27   1/29/16 190.02 193.88 189.88 193.72 210529300    189.65             1            0
28    2/1/16 192.53 194.58 191.84 193.65 136061600    189.58             2            0
29    2/2/16 191.96 191.97 189.54 190.16 182564900    186.16             3            0
30    2/3/16 191.41 191.78 187.10 191.30 205054900    187.28             4            0
31    2/4/16 190.71 192.75 189.96 191.60 139531800    187.57             0            1
32    2/5/16 190.99 191.67 187.20 187.95 180788300    184.00             0            2
33    2/8/16 185.77 186.12 182.80 185.42 191526700    181.52             0            3
34    2/9/16 183.36 186.94 183.20 185.43 184513100    181.53             0            4
35   2/10/16 186.41 188.34 185.12 185.27 148214100    181.38             0            5
36   2/11/16 182.34 184.10 181.09 182.86 219058900    179.02             0            6
37   2/12/16 184.96 186.65 183.96 186.63 127632400    182.71             1            0
38   2/16/16 188.77 189.81 187.63 189.78 120250700    185.79             2            0
39   2/17/16 191.16 193.32 191.01 192.88 136009500    188.83             3            0
40   2/18/16 193.20 193.27 191.72 192.09 102343000    188.05             4            0
41   2/19/16 191.17 192.18 190.45 192.00 114793000    187.96             5            0
42   2/22/16 193.87 194.95 193.79 194.78 103640300    190.69             6            0
43   2/23/16 194.00 194.32 192.18 192.32 111455300    188.28             0            1
44   2/24/16 190.63 193.53 189.32 193.20 150812200    189.14             1            0
45   2/25/16 193.73 195.55 192.83 195.54 110728300    191.43             2            0
46   2/26/16 196.57 196.68 194.90 195.09 129833700    190.99             3            0
47   2/29/16 195.11 196.23 193.33 193.56 125918100    189.49             4            0
48    3/1/16 195.01 198.21 194.45 198.11 141799700    193.95             5            0
49    3/2/16 197.74 199.06 197.25 199.00 102415000    194.82             6            0
50    3/3/16 198.79 199.80 198.11 199.78  95172200    195.58             7            0
51    3/4/16 200.01 201.35 199.03 200.43 129293600    196.22             8            0
52    3/7/16 199.34 201.07 199.25 200.59 100219000    196.37             9            0

  # Create initdate, from, and to charater strings
 initdate <- "2015-12-21"
 from <- "2015-12-22"
 to <- "2016-12-20"

 # Set the timezone to UTC
 Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

 # Set the currency to USD 
 currency("USD")

 stock("SPY", currency = "USD")

 # Define your trade size and initial equity
tradesize <- 100000
initeq <- 100000

# Define the names of your strategy, portfolio and account
strategy.st <- "firststrat"
portfolio.st <- "firststrat"
account.st <- "firststrat"

# Remove the existing strategy if it exists
rm.strat(strategy.st)

# initialize the portfolio
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = "SPY", initDate = initdate, currency = "USD")

# initialize the account
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD", initEq = initeq)

# initialize the orders
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)

# store the strategy
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)



    add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold", arguments = list(column ="TD.Buy.Count", 
               threshold = 8, relationship = "gt", cross = TRUE), label = "thresholdentry")
    [1] "firststrat"

    add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold", arguments = list(column ="TD.Sell.Count", 
               threshold = 8, relationship = "gt", cross = TRUE), label = "thresholdexit")
    [1] "firststrat"

    add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal", arguments = list(sigcol = "thresholdentry",
             sigval = TRUE, ordertype = "market", orderside = "long", replace = FALSE, prefer = "Open", osFUN = osMaxPos, tradeSize = tradesize, maxSize = tradesize), type = "enter")
    [1] "firststrat"

    add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal", 
    arguments = list(sigcol = "thresholdexit", sigval = TRUE, orderqty = "all",   ordertype = "market", orderside = "long", replace = FALSE, prefer = "Open"),  type = "exit")
```

Any assistance that you can provide would be most appreciated.

Comment: Updated sample from the csv file:

Comment: your sample data won't produce any signals.  perhaps edit your question and use dput to produce reproducible code?

Comment: Hi Brian, I've updated the sample. I appreciate any guidance that you have.

Answer (score 8):

You need to read the file into an xts object. You can do this with `read.zoo` and `as.xts`.

```
library(quantstrat)

# read indicators data
indicators <- read.zoo(header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE,
                       index.column = 1, format = "%m/%d/%y", text = "
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close    Volume Adj.Close TD.Sell.Count TD.Buy.Count
1   12/21/15 201.41 201.88 200.09 201.67  99094300    197.43             0            0
2   12/22/15 202.72 203.85 201.55 203.50 111026200    199.22             0            0
3   12/23/15 204.69 206.07 204.58 206.02 110987200    201.69             0            0
4   12/24/15 205.72 206.33 205.42 205.68  48539600    201.36             0            0
5   12/28/15 204.86 205.26 203.94 205.21  65899900    200.90             1            0
6   12/29/15 206.51 207.79 206.47 207.40  92640700    203.04             2            0
7   12/30/15 207.11 207.21 205.76 205.93  63317700    201.60             0            1
8   12/31/15 205.13 205.89 203.87 203.87 102929500    199.58             0            2
9     1/4/16 200.49 201.03 198.59 201.02 222353500    196.79             0            3
10    1/5/16 201.40 201.90 200.05 201.36 110845800    197.13             0            4
11    1/6/16 198.34 200.06 197.60 198.82 152112600    194.64             0            5
12    1/7/16 195.33 197.44 193.59 194.05 213436100    189.97             0            6
13    1/8/16 195.19 195.85 191.58 191.92 209817200    187.89             0            7
14   1/11/16 193.01 193.41 189.82 192.11 187941300    188.07             0            8
15   1/12/16 193.82 194.55 191.14 193.66 172330500    189.59             0            9
16   1/13/16 194.45 194.86 188.38 188.83 221168900    184.86             0           10
17   1/14/16 189.55 193.26 187.66 191.93 240795600    187.90             1            0
18   1/15/16 186.77 188.76 185.52 187.81 314240200    183.86             0            1
19   1/19/16 189.96 190.11 186.20 188.06 195244400    184.11             0            2
20   1/20/16 185.03 187.50 181.02 185.65 286547800    181.75             0            3
21   1/21/16 186.21 188.87 184.64 186.69 195772900    182.77             0            4
22   1/22/16 189.78 190.76 188.88 190.52 168319600    186.51             1            0
23   1/25/16 189.92 190.15 187.41 187.64 130371700    183.70             0            1
24   1/26/16 188.42 190.53 188.02 190.20 141036800    186.20             1            0
25   1/27/16 189.58 191.56 187.06 188.13 185681700    184.18             2            0
26   1/28/16 189.96 190.20 187.16 189.11 143798800    185.13             0            1
27   1/29/16 190.02 193.88 189.88 193.72 210529300    189.65             1            0
28    2/1/16 192.53 194.58 191.84 193.65 136061600    189.58             2            0
29    2/2/16 191.96 191.97 189.54 190.16 182564900    186.16             3            0
30    2/3/16 191.41 191.78 187.10 191.30 205054900    187.28             4            0
31    2/4/16 190.71 192.75 189.96 191.60 139531800    187.57             0            1
32    2/5/16 190.99 191.67 187.20 187.95 180788300    184.00             0            2
33    2/8/16 185.77 186.12 182.80 185.42 191526700    181.52             0            3
34    2/9/16 183.36 186.94 183.20 185.43 184513100    181.53             0            4
35   2/10/16 186.41 188.34 185.12 185.27 148214100    181.38             0            5
36   2/11/16 182.34 184.10 181.09 182.86 219058900    179.02             0            6
37   2/12/16 184.96 186.65 183.96 186.63 127632400    182.71             1            0
38   2/16/16 188.77 189.81 187.63 189.78 120250700    185.79             2            0
39   2/17/16 191.16 193.32 191.01 192.88 136009500    188.83             3            0
40   2/18/16 193.20 193.27 191.72 192.09 102343000    188.05             4            0
41   2/19/16 191.17 192.18 190.45 192.00 114793000    187.96             5            0
42   2/22/16 193.87 194.95 193.79 194.78 103640300    190.69             6            0
43   2/23/16 194.00 194.32 192.18 192.32 111455300    188.28             0            1
44   2/24/16 190.63 193.53 189.32 193.20 150812200    189.14             1            0
45   2/25/16 193.73 195.55 192.83 195.54 110728300    191.43             2            0
46   2/26/16 196.57 196.68 194.90 195.09 129833700    190.99             3            0
47   2/29/16 195.11 196.23 193.33 193.56 125918100    189.49             4            0
48    3/1/16 195.01 198.21 194.45 198.11 141799700    193.95             5            0
49    3/2/16 197.74 199.06 197.25 199.00 102415000    194.82             6            0
50    3/3/16 198.79 199.80 198.11 199.78  95172200    195.58             7            0
51    3/4/16 200.01 201.35 199.03 200.43 129293600    196.22             8            0
52    3/7/16 199.34 201.07 199.25 200.59 100219000    196.37             9            0
")
indicators <- as.xts(indicators)
```

Then the easiest thing to do is merge the indicator data with your market price data.

```
# get data for same interval as indicators
getSymbols("SPY", from = start(indicators), to = end(indicators), adjust = TRUE)

# merge indicators with data
SPY <- merge(SPY, indicators[, c("TD.Sell.Count", "TD.Buy.Count")])
```

Now you can setup your strategy. Note that you do not need to set `initDate` (and can actually create problems for yourself if you set it incorrectly), and you need to set a position limit using `addPosLimit` if you want to use `osMaxPos`. I also reduced the `threshold` from 8 to 6 to get one entry and one exit signal.

```
# Set the timezone to UTC
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

# Set the currency to USD 
currency("USD")
stock("SPY", currency = "USD")

# Define your trade size and initial equity
tradesize <- 100000
initeq <- 100000

# Define the names of your strategy, portfolio and account
strategy.st <- "firststrat"
portfolio.st <- "firststrat"
account.st <- "firststrat"

# Remove the existing strategy if it exists
rm.strat(strategy.st)

# initialize the portfolio
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = "SPY")

# initialize the account
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initEq = initeq)

# initialize the orders
initOrders(portfolio.st)

# set position limits
addPosLimit(portfolio.st, "SPY", start(SPY), 100)

# store the strategy
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "TD.Buy.Count",
                            threshold = 6,
                            relationship = "gt",
                            cross = TRUE),
           label = "thresholdentry")

add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "TD.Sell.Count",
                            threshold = 6,
                            relationship = "gt",
                            cross = TRUE),
           label = "thresholdexit")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "thresholdentry",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          orderqty = 100,
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open",
                          osFUN = osMaxPos,
                          tradeSize = tradesize,
                          maxSize = tradesize),
         type = "enter")

add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
         arguments = list(sigcol = "thresholdexit",
                          sigval = TRUE,
                          orderqty = "all",
                          ordertype = "market",
                          orderside = "long",
                          replace = FALSE,
                          prefer = "Open"),
         type = "exit")

applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolio.st)
# [1] "2016-01-11 00:00:00 SPY 100 @ 193.009995"
# [1] "2016-03-04 00:00:00 SPY -100 @ 200.009995"
```

Comment: Thanks Josh really appreciate the help. I'm trying to add additional rules to the code that involve moving averages, ie sell out once closing price is < SMA 200. However, upon adding the relevant code for the SMA, I receive the following error code : Error in runSum(x, n) : Invalid 'n'.

Comment: @Tyler: That means `n` is less than 1 or `> NROW(x)`. So my guess is that your data object doesn't have 200 values. If that's not the case, post a new question with a minimal reproducible example.